# Hierarchical tick-labels in PGF plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm looking for a way to create hierarchical tick-labels in tikz/pdfplots - like in this example picture:
[image]

The 1st three groups describe the results of experiment A, with parameters 0, 4 and 8, the 2nd three groups do the same for experiment B, and so on.

However, I have no idea how to achieve this, and so far couldn't find any info online. Does anyone have a hint or solution for this problem? Many thanks for reading this!

Here is my code so far, where I didn't come up with a better solution than writing the parameter in parentheses and repeating the name of the experiment over and over again...

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable} % plots
\tikzset{every picture/.style={/utils/exec={\sffamily}}} % font for plots
\tikzset{every picture/.style={font=\small}} % font size for plots
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=12cm,
        height=8cm,
        ymax=93,
        ymin=0,
        ybar,
        bar width=4pt,
        symbolic x coords={A (0), A (4), A (8), B (0), B (4), B (8), C (0), C (4), C (8)},
        xtick=data,
        x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east}]

    \addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {
        (A (0),61.682)
        (A (4),63.104)
        (A (8),60.82)
        
        (B (0),65.454)
        (B (4),65.396)
        (B (8),63.69)
        
        (C (0),77.73)
        (C (4),75.756)
        (C (8),70.29)};

    \addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {
        (A (0),35.632)
        (A (4),34.65)
        (A (8),36.76) 
        
        (B (0),32.596)
        (B (4),32.47)
        (B (8),34.14)
        
        (C (0),21.58)
        (C (4),23.364)
        (C (8),28.87)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the right xticks, you can combine `xtick` and `xticklabels`. After that, nodes can be used to position the group titles **A**, **B** and **C**. For this, clipping must be switched off.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable} % plots
\tikzset{every picture/.style={/utils/exec={\sffamily}}} % font for plots
\tikzset{every picture/.style={font=\small}} % font size for plots
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=12cm,
        height=8cm,
        ymax=93,
        ymin=0,
        ybar,
        bar width=8pt,
        % x ticks explicitly formatted
        xtick={1,2,3,5,6,7,9,10,11},
        xticklabels={$0$,$4$,$8$,$0$,$4$,$8$,$0$,$4$,$8$},
        % turn of clipping
        clip=false
    ]

    \addplot+[ybar] plot 
        coordinates {
            (1,61.682)
            (2,63.104)
            (3,60.82)

            (5,65.454)
            (6,65.396)
            (7,63.69)

            (9,77.73)
            (10,75.756)
            (11,70.29)
        };

    \addplot+[ybar] plot
        coordinates {
            (1,35.632)
            (2,34.65)
            (3,36.76) 

            (5,32.596)
            (6,32.47)
            (7,34.14)

            (9,21.58)
            (10,23.364)
            (11,28.87)
        };

    \node[font=\bfseries] at (xticklabel cs:.1675,10pt) {A};
    \node[font=\bfseries] at (xticklabel cs:.5000,10pt) {B};
    \node[font=\bfseries] at (xticklabel cs:.8325,10pt) {C};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]